# How do reducer group the input data within a partition?

Tags: java, hadoop, reducers

So I have two Mappers and one Reducer. The keys outputted from the first mapper are of the form "*interest1*::user" with some value. While the keys outputted from the second mapper are of the form "*interest2*::interest" Here *interest1* and *interest2* are variables while "user" and "interest" are string literals. I am using a partitioner which splits the keys from the mappers on "::" and only considers the first split for hashing and determining the reducer.

Now the from the reducer point of view, it will see keys in sorted order which means "interest1::interest" will come before "interest1::user" going by the alphabetical order. The reducer logic requires that these key-value pairs are handled by the same reduce task. I am using static variables to store all interests and then output those interests with users later on when all users have been collected.

Lets see an example.
mapper1 output is as follows

```
k1::interest -> val1
k2::interest -> val2
k1::interest -> val3
```

mapper2 output is as follows:

```
k2::user -> val5
k2::user -> val8
k1::user -> val9
```

Now after going through the partitioner, the reducer will see the following records.

```
k1::interest -> val1
k1::interest -> val3
k1::user -> val9
k2::interest -> val2
k2::user -> val5
k2::user -> val8
```

Now my reducer logic requires that all the key-value paris with k1 should go to the same task. While key-value pairs with k2 can go to another task. Does hadoop launches multiple tasks within the same partition or can we safely say that only one task is launched per partition. In case of multiple tasks, do I have to worry about the reducer input to get split unevenly i.e.

```
k1::interest -> val1
k1::interest -> val3
```

will be hanlded by one task.

```
k1::user -> val9
k2::interest -> val2
```

will be handled by another task

```
k2::user -> val5
k2::user -> val8
```

will be hanlded by yet another task.

Do I have to use grouping comparator here? I don't need sorting on the values just the gaurantee that key-value pairs with a particular prefix end up being handled by the same task or serial invocation of the reduce function within the same input group.